# Matching the stored values and queries in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-nested

I have a field called that is inside a nested field "name" that is a "Keyword" in elastic search.

Name field contains 2 values.

1. Jagannathan Rajagopalan
2. Rajagopalan.

If I query "Rajagopalan", I should get only the item #2.
If I query the complete Jagannathan Rajagopalan, I should get #1.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) which is used for exact search. Added a working example according to your use-case.

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "name" : {
        "keyword" : "Jagannathan Rajagopalan"
    }
}
```

And another doc

```
{
    "name" : {
        "keyword" : "Jagannathan"
    }
}
```

**And search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "name",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name.keyword": "Jagannathan Rajagopalan"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
   "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "key",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "name": {
                        "keyword": "Jagannathan Rajagopalan"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: sry for not being clear earlier. The field inside a nested type. It does not work in that scenario

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan ohh its under nested, can you please provide your index-mapping and sample document, I will change the query, you just need to give the `nested path`

Comment: Thanks. I missed the .keyword. Does it needed, if we declare it as a keyword type?

Comment: @jagannathanrajagopalan, no if its already defined as a keyword in your mapping, its not  required, in my case, its the name of field so I used it :)